# Geting java.lang.IllegalAccessError when i tried to create Simple Chrome Driver object

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package org.apache.maven.artifact;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
//import org.openqa.selenium.ie.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
        // WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        // WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
    }
}
```

For IE and Firefox getting Java exception as connection Refused.
For chrome getting

> : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V
>   from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker

Comment: Which version of `JDK` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

While working with *Selenium v3.x* you have to download either [*GeckoDriver*](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), [*ChromeDriver*](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) or [*IEDriverServer*](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and store in your system. Next you have to mention the absolute path either of the *GeckoDriver*, *ChromeDriver* or *IEDriverServer* through `System.setProperty()` line through **either** of the following options (**but not all**) :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
//or
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
//or
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\IEDriverServer.exe")
```

### System.setProperty()

[`java.lang.System.setProperty()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_setproperty.htm) method sets the system property indicated by the specified *key*.

- Declaration :

  ```
  public static String setProperty(String key, String value)
  ```
- Parameters :

  ```
  key - This is the name of the system property.
  value - This is the value of the system property.
  ```
- Exception :

  - SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkPermission method doesn't allow setting of the specified property.
  - NullPointerException - if key or value is null.
  - IllegalArgumentException - if key is empty.

Now, as per the `System.setProperty()` line you can initialize the matching *WebDriver* instance as follows :

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
//or
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//or
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```